# Is it possible not to have an ssh password for a user when coming from a specific network?

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords

I would like to login to ssh without providing a password when connecting from a specific network (I am aware of the risk).

**Is this something which can be configured?**

Please note that I am not refering to key-based authentication (which I have in place for exposed networks), but the ability to type a login and be authenticated without the need to input the password for that user.

Comment: see option 3 in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406245/limit-ssh-access-to-specific-clients-by-ip-address)

Comment: so you want to be prompted for a password from all the network except for one subnet? not sure if this will work as ssh except maybe if that user has no password and you set Match Address section and set your subnet with PermitEmptyPasswords and the rest of the network with PubkeyAuthentication. Just an idea, never tried this. But this will of course add security risks, so think twice before you set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, something like this:

```
sshpass -pfoobar ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host command_to_run
```

[sshpass](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass) is a utility designed for running ssh using the mode referred to as "keyboard-interactive" password authentication, but in non-interactive mode.

ssh uses direct TTY access to make sure that the password is indeed issued by an interactive keyboard user. Sshpass runs ssh in a dedicated tty, fooling it into thinking it is getting the password from an interactive user.

The command to run is specified after sshpass' own options. Typically it will be "ssh" with arguments, but it can just as well be any other command. The password prompt used by ssh is, however, currently hardcoded into sshpass.

Comment: this solution needs to have the password entered at least one time. don't think this is what the OP wanted to achieve. but let him speak for himself.